# How to set 2 different hyperlink style in particular div

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I want to implement 2 color variations in hyperlinks in particular div. Is it possible?

CSS:

```
.postfull a:link, a:hover {
    color: #D80003;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.ext a:link, a:hover {
    color: #036C0C !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="postfull">
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="ext"> Marseille port</a> is one of the most important it adapted to the rough challenges presented by the changes of the different era to become of the most important assets in the <a href="#" >Mediterranean Basin</a>. 
    </p>     
</div>
```

Comment: Meaning you want to have different color for two `a` in same `div` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. But in your case you have a little syntax error. In the below code you have applied the child element of .ext class. But In your code it is not a child. It is sibling element.

```
.ext a:link, a:hover {
color: #036C0C !important;
text-decoration:none;
 }
```

So update your code like below.

```
.ext + a:link, .ext + a:hover {
color: #036C0C !important;
text-decoration:none;
 }
```

[**Little Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6WfY/)

Comment: demo is working fine but our webpage links not working this method http://francetravelwiki.com/lyon.php

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `.ext a:link, a:hover` with `.ext:link, .ext:hover` code:

```
.ext:link, .ext:hover {
   color: #036C0C !important;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: thanx for your reply. but this method is not working for me working fine but our webpage links not working this method http://francetravelwiki.com/lyon.php :(

Comment: hey its working re . pleas check custom.css line 7 you have added #3570c3 color please change that color then only you will able to see changes.